# Remove scrollbar from pdf image in HTML RMarkdown document

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, scrollbar

I can't figure out why pdf images I'm inserting into my HTML RMarkdown document are appearing inside of itty bitty scroll boxes with both vertical and horizontal scrollbars. This doesn't happen if I convert the same image to .png

The pdf image appears this way if inserted like so:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, eval = TRUE}
knitr::include_graphics("image.pdf")
```
````

or like so:

```
![](image.pdf)
```

I have an option set to include scroll bars in my code chunks, but if I remove it and re-knit the document the itty bitty image scroll box remains so this is not causing the problem (and is the only non-default setting):

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
pre code, pre, code {
  white-space: pre !important;
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
  word-break: keep-all !important;
  word-wrap: initial !important;
}
```
````

Changing the option `out.width = '100%'` is resizing the scrollbox a bit but not removing it. Note that the pdf image is 6 x 2.5 inches, so not unreasonably large or anything. Any ideas to make my inserted pdf image not be in a scroll box at all? Thanks!

Comment: @KJ thanks! By adjusting the width I did remove the horizontal scroll, but the vertical box size is really small and changing height doesn't change anything. I guess a more specific way to ask my question is: How do I increase the size of the box that the pdf displays in?